# Função ajax com php não está funcionando

Tags: php, ajax, pdo

Tenho esse codigo mais o ajax nao traz nem um valor

```
  $.ajax({

    url: 'php/vizCliente.class.php',
    type: 'POST',
     data: {
              update:      '1'
            },
    cache: false,
    datatype: "json",
    error: function(e) {
        alert('Erro ao tentar ação! \n'+e);
    },
    success: function(data) {
        alert(data);

    },
  });
});
```

Esse e o codigo em php

```
final class vizCliente
{

public $update;

public function __construct()
        {

                $this->update           = $_POST['update'];


                if($this->update == '1')
                {
                                    echo $this->update;                        

                }

        }
}
```

Comment: E como você fez a instância da classe no PHP?

Answer (score 0):

Sua classe está declarada em `vizCliente.class.php`, porém não há neste arquivo nenhuma instância da classe, você deve instanciar a classe e preencher seus valores.